Confusing use of "if" in "Advanced Grammar in Use"
I'm currently leafing through Advanced Grammar in Use by Martin Hewings and on page 18 there is a unit (unit 9) describing the difference between "will" and "be going to". Among other rules, there is this pair of sentences:

I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade, if you want some. (= I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade. Do you want some?)

and

I'll open a bottle of lemonade if you want some. (= If you say you want some, I'll open it)

The difference between mentioned "will"  and "be going to" is completely clear to me here, but suddenly there is a new puzzle: this "if" in the first sentence. What does this "if" mean here, if it doesn't make any condition on the opening the bottle part - considering that there is no condition in "Do you want some?"? Is this "if" is some short form of "(I wonder) if you want some"? But in this case shouldn't it be a separate interrogative sentence - "I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade. (I wonder) if you want some?". Or maybe there is a completely different explanation... I'm completely puzzled about this "if-not-being-if".
And, btw, the use of commas in these two sentences in the book is not clear to me too: there is one in the first sentence but there is no in the second one.

Please don't say "leafing through a grammar book" without mentioning the title of the book.  If you can link to the book on the internet too that is even better.

In colloquial/informal/spoken English "If" can have various meanings.  This might not be explained in a grammar book TBH. You might have better luck using a good dictionary. The word "if" isn't always a conditional. It can be used to imply an indirect question. Another example: We're going to a restaurant, if you want to come.  This is an indirect question asking if you'd like to come along too.

I found the book's title, author and even a publicly accessible copy on the internet archive.

I find it amazing that so many users, both new and old, can talk about something read in a grammar book without ever mentioning the title. What  is the motivation behind this? Why?

I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade if you want some.  How can that be ambiguous?  Maybe this will disambiguate it for you: I'm not going to open a bottle of lemonade if you don't want any.

@Lambie: The comma suggests very strongly that the interpretation in Billy Kerr's comment is what is intended here: "I'm going to open a bottle if lemonade; and if you want some,...[you are welcome to partake]". Your claim that the sentence unambiguously means something else is untenable.

@TonyK But that is not how it is written. I can rewrite all sorts of stuff. Also, I see nothing non-standard about If you want some. Here the if is conditional and very understandable as written. The comma makes little difference to either sentence. I'm going to open the lemonade if you want some. If you don't, I won't.

Good observation! There are actually a few uses of "if":

The canonical case is that whether something happens or is true depends on a condition: "If it rains, you'll get wet." The "if" part (raining) causes or allows the other part (getting wet) to happen.

Another case is about evidence: "If you see holes in the walls, you have mice." The "if" part is the evidence leading to an inference. (Linguists call this an epistemic conditional.)

"I have lemonade if you want some": This is a way of saying the information may be useful to the addressee. What is conditioned is the relevance or helpfulness, not factuality, of the information that the speaker has lemonade. (Linguists call this a pragmatic or speech act conditional.)


[citation for the 3 types: Croft (2022), Morphosyntax, p. 529]

Sometimes comedians make jokes about the weirdness of this form of conditional. For example: "If you enjoyed the show, I'm Bob. [implying you can use this information to give a good review.] If you didn't enjoy the show, I'm Santa Claus. [or another obviously fake name.]"

@GlennWillen That joke seems to be based on the fact that when a performer says, "If you enjoyed the show, I'm Bob," they almost certainly want you to understand the sentence as a simple conditional (the "canonical" case): if you liked the show, help me build my reputation. A joke that I think is more in line with the third usage is, "I have lemonade if you want some. And I have lemonade if you don't want some."

I completely agree that "the going to/will difference...is not due to the if clause at all." I understood the question to be about why an if-clause can express something other than a semantic condition ("if-not-being-if"). There is also a side question about commas which I didn't attempt to answer here but it is discussed in another answer.

@nschneid OP was very clear that they were wondering about this whole different meaning of "if", which is exactly what you explained (and I was just about to write more or less the same answer when you posted yours).

See my comment on What type of conditional clause is this?. Yes, often these "if" constructions omit and imply extra words, like "I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade, [and you can have some] if you want some."
There's no comma in "I'll open a bottle of lemonade if you want some," simply because it doesn't need it. The "if" is meant literally, "I will X if you Y." But in a sentence like "I'm going to lunch, if you want to come," the comma helps represent the omitted thoughts, like "I'm going to lunch [and I'm inviting you], if you want to come."
Update: I actually ran across an instance of this while watching Avatar: The Last Airbender a few hours after writing this answer.

I've never seen such a fine specimen of lemur. That beast would fetch me a hefty sum if you'd be interested in bartering.

Obviously the owner's willingness has no direct bearing on the lemur's value; it conflates "if you were to barter it to me, I could resell it for a hefty sum."

The last paragraph is debatable; the consequent is that the speaker would be able to sell it for a high price, not merely that it has a high value. And the speaker indeed can't sell it if they do not acquire it first.

"I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade, [and you can have some] if you want some." There is no omission. I'm going to have a cup of tea, if you want some. means: I'm having it regardless and you can have one too, if you want to, but it's not an offer.

Compare:

She's not dating anyone at the moment, if you were wondering whether to ask her to the dance.
She's not dating anyone at the moment, in case you were wondering whether to ask her to the dance.

The subordinate clause provides an explanation for the speaker making the statement in the main clause, which might seem to have been "out of the blue".  Without that if-clause, the conversation might go like this:

She's not dating anyone at the moment.
-- Why are you telling me this?
In case you were wondering whether to ask her to the dance.
-- Why do you think I would be wondering that?
Who do you think you're fooling? I see you stealing glances at her every chance you get.

You could reverse the order of the clauses:

If you were wondering whether to ask her to the dance, she's not dating anyone at the moment.

Putting the if-clause up front  opens with a context for the ensuing statement in the main clause.
P.S. The implicit unspoken elliptical result of the if-condition is something like "then you may be interested to know", and the main clause declares the fact you might like to know:

If you were wondering whether to ask her to the dance then you may be interested to know she's not dating anyone at the moment.


Some people take issue with this usage, since strictly speaking, the grammar is nonsense. The kind of logical link you'd expect between the two clauses just doesn't exist. Nevertheless, it's used and understood.
"If you want some" is really modifying some other omitted thing, and there are a few options for what that might be. I think the following is closest to how I personally parse it:

I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade, just so you know if you want some.

I'm telling you that I'm opening lemonade so that, if you want some, you know about it.
But it's possible to keep it much more straightforward:

I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade; if you want some, you can have it.

This is a pretty unique quirk of English, one I'm surprised to see formally prescribed. Even so, your book is correct; this is one of the rare cases where "will" and "[be] going to" contrast in meaning.

It's not nearly unique to English and happens in most languages!  And in twenty years of language teaching at schools and universities II've never heard anybody take issue with this usage! Or read any objections either. In spoken English it may well be the most common use of the conditional there is.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I meant unique within English grammar, and maybe I'm wrong about that too. I have my doubts about "most common use of the conditional" though.

"I'm telling you that I'm opening lemonade so that, if you want some, you know about it." This doesn't seem any more logical than the original sentence ─ since you've told them, they will know about it even if they don't want some!

@the-baby-is-you Note I said "spoken English". Go to COCA Press SEARCH. Type in " . If you" So without the question marks: Full stop, space, if with a capital 'I', space, you . Then press 'find matching strings', then press 'CONTEXT', then on the top right in blue, press 'GENRE', select 'SPOKEN'. Look at the results: about 70-80% relevance conditionals.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. It's funny how all these answers miss the main point: definite action + if you want to be part of it versus an offer for you to be part of it. And some don't even deal with it. Go figure. But I agree, ain't nothing off about the grammar at all.

In your first example, the clause is non-restrictive and gets a comma. The actual meaning of the sentence is more like "I am going to open a bottle of lemonade, whether you want some or not. Do you want some?" In the second, the clause is restrictive and does not take a comma. The speaker is saying "I will open a bottle of lemonade only if you want some." The restrictive/non-restrictive nature of the clause determines the use of a comma. That's what I was taught many years ago.

I feel like this addresses the real issue, more than the defintion of "if."  This answer could be improved if it cited sources.  For example, Chicago Manual of Style (16th edition) section 6.31 "A dependent clause...should not be preceded by a comma if it is restrictive....: We will agree to the proposal if you accept our conditions. If the dependent clause is merely supplementary or parenthetical, it should be preceded by a comma. I'd like the tom yum, if you don't mind."

"I have lemonade if you want some" seems perfectly natural to me without the comma/pause in speech. The 'only if' interpretation is implausible here.

Syntax Junkie: You're right, and I was aware of that when I posted my answer. However, the only source I could cite was the recesses of my brain. My original sources were my high school English books, from going on 60 years ago.

The overall offer in either statement is the same:

"Let me know if you want some lemonade and I will serve you some lemonade."

The slight difference is whether the bottle is opened conditionally-on or regardless-of the listener's response.
While the book's rephrasings of the sentences convey the correct implied meanings, it may perhaps be clearer to treat the statements as having made the following omissions/ellipses.

(1a) I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade, if you want some.
(1b)  I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade, if you want some (let me know and I'll serve you some).


(2a) I'll open a bottle of lemonade if you want some.
(2b) I'll open a bottle of lemonade (and serve you some) if (you let me know) you want some.

This way it is easier to see that "if" doesn't change in meaning, but rather it is "am going to" and "will" that have different nuance in the sentence.
The nuance of "am going to" in the first pair of sentences is that it is treated as a statement of fact.  Regardless of the listener's response the speaker is going to open the bottle either way.
The nuance of the "will" in the second pair of sentences is that it is treated as a promise.  Depending upon the listener's response, the speaker either will open the bottle or they won't open the bottle.

Another similar example would be:

(1a) I'm going to the store, if you need anything.
(1b)  I'm going to the store; if you need anything (you should let me know now what to purchase).


(2a) I will go to the store if you need anything.
(2b) I promise to go to the store if you need me to purchase anything from the store.


The overall offer in either statement is the same:. Not true at all. One is a statement of fact and a definite action. The other is not.

The if here is the normal if, but the phrase, "if you want" is often a sort of implicit invitation to partake in whatever's being talked about.
The first example is essentially shorthand for something like:

I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade, (and) if you want some (you can have some).

The if is conditional, but it's not conditioning over whether or not the bottle is opened, it's conditioning over whether or not you will have any.
Another example might be, "we're going to the restaurant, if you want to come." The if has nothing to do with whether or not the speaker is going to go to the restaurant. They're saying you can come too if you want to.
You could use a comma in the second example, but it would be unnecessary. The comma in the first example is necessary because otherwise it would look too much like the first part is conditioned on the second part.

In terms of teaching uses in English:
will is used to offer to do something:

If you're hot, I'll open the window.

If you're willing,she'll do the housework now.

I'll open a bottle of lemonade if you want some. [an offer]

If you don't, I won't. [continuation of previous sentence]


English lessons from the British Council

Promises, offers and requests We use I will or We will to make promises and offers:

I'll give you a lift home after the party.
We'll come and see you next week.


This use of will is equally true in BrE and AmE. It also applies to third person if you speaking in that person's name:

He'll finish the job now, if you agree.

The conditionality [if] of the action is dependent on the person's accepting the offer made by the speaker.

I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade, if you want some.
I'm not going to open a bottle of lemonade if you don't want any.

I think the negative makes the use of if in the first sentence perfectly clear. I don't see how to explain it more clearly. The action of the main clause depends on a condition the speaker of that clause assigns to the second person in the conversation. This is a standard speech usage. "I'm going to do something" + if you [verb] is a definite action, not an offer to do something for someone.
I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade, if you want some. = I am doing it and you can have some since that is what I wiil be doing.
Another example:

I'm going to leave early tomorrow if that is what you want me to do.


This is the clearest description of why a native speaker knows that opening a bottle of lemonade is conditional in the second sentence, but not in the first.
It’s worth noting that “will have” is an exception to this rule. “I will buy eggs tomorrow if you need them” is strongly conditional (the speaker will buy eggs only if the listener wants them), but “I will have eggs tomorrow if you need them” is not (the speaker will possess the eggs whether or not the listener wants them).

@KrisW Both are conditional. The first is conditional because the speaker assigns the condition to another and the second with will is an offer.

I should have said “dependent”. To me (BrEng) there's a very clear difference in meaning. The “going to” form is independent: it tells me that the speaker is carrying out the action regardless of whether the if-clause is true.  Use “will” and the action becomes dependent on the if-clause being true.  Both are offers, but “going to” is an offer to share in the result of whatever is being done, while “will” is an offer to do something.   Your “going to leave early” example does not make sense to me as you have expanded it. My understanding would be “…if you want [to leave early too]”.

@KrisW Many if conditionals concern one speaker. Here we have a speaker addressing someone. Also, the British English thing here is not relevant ...at all. I'm going to x is what the speaker is definitely going to do. I will here is an offer plain and simple. "I'll put the kettle on, if that's what you want". "going to" is not used for offers.

@KrisW Really? How about "We'll be there at 5, if you want to join us" or "The royal family will be there, if you enjoy hobnobbing with those kinds of people"

Where do you explain the difference between going to and will?

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Will is an offer, "going to open" is the action of the main clause.

@Lambie, the difference between “going to... if”, and “will ... if” is basically the OP’s question.  They say they understand the difference, but by asking about the meaning of “if” it’s clear they do not for this kind of sentence. And we are in agreement that “going to” is not dependent, while “will” is. I consider both forms to be offers, though.

@Aracaria - in your first sentence, delete “join us” and you’re left with the dependent offer form again - with your expansion, “if you want to join us”, it’s explicit that the action is independent: the event is happening regardless.  Your second sentence doesn’t fit the offer form because the if-clause (“you enjoy hobnobbing...”) is not about the listener’s desire for the first clause to be true.  Change it to “the Royal Family will be there if you like” and suddenly you’ve got an improbable offer from the speaker to summon the House of Windsor to a social event.

@KrisW  You needn't tell me what the question is, I know it. "I'm going to open a bottle of lemonade" is a statement of fact about me, and, by the way, if you want some, I'll give you some but I'm going to do it regardless of whether you want some or not whereas "I'll open a bottle of lemonade, if you want some" is only happening, if you want some, otherwise, I won't open the damn bottle. :)

@KrisW You seem to have grasped the fundamental part of the grammar that you were previously missing ;-) Whether conditionals are seen as relevance conditionals or indicatives is about the context, i.e. the pragmatics, and not about which verb form appears in the protasis.  The subtleties of a given verb form may have this or that effect in one context and a completely different one in another. In general the verb forms have no effects at all.  It's pragmatics all the way down., And that's one thing the voluminous professional literature on the subject all agrees on.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore - no context is required. The “going to” version of this sentence an idiom. The choice of “will” versus ”going to”, in British usage does change the meaning of sentences like this, despite both versions having the same literal meaning. (I cannot speak for American usage, but my feeling is that the distinction is there too)
I am deliberately avoiding technical terms in my comments here, by the way: after all this is a forum for people who are learning English. The first rule of writing, even academic writing, is to consider your audience. This is not a journal.

@KrisW "going to" is not an idiom. And idiom might be: going to hell in a handbasket. Once again, I have to say here, that BrE and AmE are exactly the same thing here. Those kinds of utterances remain stable on both sides of the pond and there are no grammatical differences such as what you point out between the two. But I agree with you that there is no point in overburdening OPs with technical grammar terms unless necessary.

@KrisW Some comments here need to be directed to the people who are advising learners. The basic point is there is no helpful generalisation to be made between 'going to' and 'will' in the main clauses of conditionals in terms of what type of conditionality is being conveyed.

@Lambie, I didn’t say “going to” on its own was an idiom. What I have said, repeatedly now, is that in this exact pattern of sentence, the choice of using “going to“ rather than “will” is an idiom insofar as it the perceived meaning changes, despite “going to” and “will” having literally identical meanings.  Literally, what is the difference between: “I will get cookies, if you want some” and “I am going to get cookies, if you want some”? I know the difference, yet “will” and “going to” have literally the same meaning.

@KrisW No, they don't have the same meaning and I guess you have never taught English. Please look up the use of "will". Please read my answer. An idiom is a set phrase in English; it is not use of a verb form or tense.

@Lambie This is getting ridiculous. We never disagreed about going-to/will - that was the other dude’s problem. The first comment I addressed to you on this post was all I wanted to say. Then that other poster butted in and we have been dragged into a tar-pit of literalism and nonsense. I won’t continue it.
